# How to update a specific value inside ng-repeat in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a code that gets all the products in my api
:

**Controller**

```
loadProducts();

function loadProducts() {
  $http.get('/api/products').then(function(response) {
    $scope.products = response.data
  });
}

$scope.Update = function(id) {
  //do update code here and when it succeeds, load products function
  loadProducts();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Action</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="p in products">
  <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ p.name }} </td>
  <td><a ng-click="Update(p.id)"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The code is working though I have lots of data being loaded that whenever I update a single item, the whole data will be loaded again.

Is there a way that for example, I updated a single item,and it will be the only one being loaded instead of `loadProducts();` loading everything?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What will be the new data, I mean what do you want to update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On recalling of loadProducts from update your fetching same data....so you dont need to call it again.....only if u want to fetch some new based on some id or something then only you need it......have a look at below code how to replace the existing array data with index value

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
    {"id":1,"name":"a"},
     {"id":2,"name":"b"},
      {"id":3,"name":"c"},
       {"id":4,"name":"d"},
    ];
    
    $scope.Update = function(id,index) {
  $scope.products[index].name="h";
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
<tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Action</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="p in products">
  <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ p.name }} </td>
   <td><button ng-click="Update(p.id,$index)">upit</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here i added a sample data for you and when you click on a upit i am passing the index value to update function....by using this i am overriding the name property...like if you have new data from api then also you use this by fetching the data first and inserting like this.

Comment: What if I have a table ng-repeat with a button each to view more data in a modal. And then update it there. Will this code work too?

Comment: you mean single button for whole table or a button for each table row??if its button for each row this will work for sure

Comment: Button for each row. The button has viewmodal(p.id) and then inside the modal is the update button with the id too update(id)

Comment: Uhm, the snippet is same?

Comment: are u not seeing button for upit?

Comment: I can see it. Let me try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131595/discussion-between-sa-e-chowdary-and-fewflyby).

Answer (score 1):

Do not call loadProducts() on updating each item. Since angular supports [**`Two-way data`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) binding ,whenever you update data it will remain on the client side.

```
$scope.Update = function(id) {
  //remove from here
  loadProducts();
}
```

Once everything is updated, provide a way to store it on the server side. Load all the products, whenever an application is loaded initially.

In order to limit the data that needs to be shown on the interface, you can use **[limitTO](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)** inside ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in products | limitTo : 100">
  <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ p.name }} </td>
  <td><a ng-click="Update(p.id)"></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Once he's doing so I believe he ain't using the array's object itself, if he did the desired behavior would have been accomplished, but a new instance, but two way data binding is surely the answer

Answer (score 1):

No need to call `loadProducts` again, simply update the existing `products` array

```
$scope.Update = function(id, $index) {
  //do update code here and when it succeeds, update the existing products array
  $scope.products[$index] = updatedProduct;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
Use `$index` to track the index of the ng-repeat.

```
   <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
      <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.name }} </td>
      <td><a ng-click="Update($index)"></a></td>
    </tr>
```

Inside your controller:

```
$scope.Update = function(index) {
  $scope.products[index].name = newValue; //Update Name of a particular Product
}
```

This edition will be populated to the View.

Option 2:
Pass the product as a parameter to the controller function `Update` .

```
   <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
      <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ p.name }} </td>
      <td><a ng-click="Update(p)"></a></td>
    </tr>
```

Inside your controller:

```
$scope.Update = function(product) {
  product.name = newName; //Update Name of a particular Product
}
```

Comment: passing index wont work if you are using any filter.

Comment: please check, I Added second option.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the **property and index** to update. $index you can get the current item index. Also if you need to update the second item only in products then you can check it $index==2.

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in products">
  <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ p.name }} </td>
  <td><a ng-click="Update(p.id, $index)"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

    $scope.Update = function(id, index) {

      $scope.products[index] = updatedProduct;
    }
```